# Best way to create a List without duplicates?

Tags: scala

I have a HashMap containing a mapping of old URIs (keys) to their replacement URIs (values). Several of the older values have been combined, meaning that there are duplicate values. Here's a small example showing what the data looks like (obviously not real websites):

```
http://oldaddress1.com -> http://newaddress1.com
http://oldaddress2.com -> http://newaddress2.com
http://oldaddress3.com -> http://newaddress2.com
```

I need to extract only the unique new addresses from the map in the most efficient way possible, as it is quite a large dataset. From the example above, I would need to generate a list which has the following values:

```
list(0) = http://newaddress1.com
list(1) = http://newaddress2.com
```

My first thought was to use an **ArrayBuffer**'s contains method like so:

```
if (!(list contains newAddress)) list += newAddress
```

But it occured to me that this might involve scanning over a lot of data several times unless the method has a more efficient way of checking for a duplicate than by scanning the entire list.

I am also aware that I could easily use a map for this, but it would be easier for the purposes of what I am trying to do to have it in a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most efficient way to go would be to use a [`Set[String]`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Set.html).

```
val map = Map("hello" -> "world", "again" -> "world")
val res: Set[String] = map.values.toSet
```

Yields:

```
res: Set[String] = Set(world)
```

In general, I'd refer to the [Wikipedia value about set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) for an interesting read of it's properties and applications.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!